# Quotes within quotes applescript

Tags: osx-lion, applescript

I am doing an applescript that is supposed to set an command with quotes an variable. This is the code so far:

```
set myString to "This is a "quoted" text."
```

But an error occurs because applescript doesn't allow quotes within quotes. I have tried to take backslash before each quotes but then the output is:

```
"This is a \"quoted\" text."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\"my quoted text\" is the proper way to wrap text in double quotes. Run the script below and open example.txt to see the result.

```
set xxx to "This is a \"quoted\" text."
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of xxx & " > ~/Desktop/example.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

Directly from Apple, it says you can use the escape:

**Option 1:**

[Special String Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html)

```
The backslash (\) and double-quote (") characters have special meaning
in text. AppleScript encloses text in double-quote characters and uses
the backslash character to represent return (\r), tab (\t), and
linefeed (\n) characters (described below). So if you want to include
an actual backslash or double-quote character in a text object, you
must use the equivalent two-character sequence. As a convenience,
AppleScript also provides the text constant quote, which has the value
\".

Table 6-1  Special characters in text Character To insert in text
Backslash character (\) \\ Double quote (") \" quote (text constant)
```

**Option 2**

On that same page, Apple says you can use `quote` to insert `\"` instead:

```
set myString to "this is a " & quote & "quoted" & quote & " text."
```

**Option 3**

Another option found is:

```
set inString to "quoted"
set myString to "this is a " & quoted form of inString & " text."
```

**Edit:** Though, you said that last one outputs `this is 'quoted' text`.

Comment: The output of that is "this is a 'quoted' text.". It didn't work...

Comment: Option 1 and 2 gives "this is a \"quoted\" text." and Option 3 gives not real quotes, "this is a 'quoted' text."

Comment: @ThePhone Understood, just quoting directly from the Apple Developer Docs.  Hopefully someone can enlighten us on why that's not working.

Comment: `quoted form of` is meant for escaping strings for `do shell script`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in applescript, if you run the command `return TestVarible`
 
the output is with backslashes. But, the final command is correct:

`display dialog TestVariable` Output `"This is a "quoted" text."`

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: It's not a bug. AppleScript Editor just displays result strings with the AppleScript syntax.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Any string "result" in a developer tool should be shown as a literal, so that you know exactly what the output is. It would save a lot of headaches like this during debugging, when you have complex strings with lots of slashes and escapes, etc. For example, JavaScript's `console.log( "\"abc\"")` logs `"abc"`, not `\"abc\"` or `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

other way for quoted text in applescript :

set input to "with quote"

set input to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of (quote & input & quote)

echo '\"with quote\"'

or more long

set input to do shell script "echo " & input & " | sed 's#" & input & "#" & "\"" & input & "\"" & " #'"

Comment: Without proper formatting it's hard to tell which lines are commands and which are comments. Could you please edit your answer? (Hint: start commands with four spaces to get them formatted as such)